# Bootstrap Slider : Issue during fetching selected value

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My code:

```html
<input id="ex19" type="text"
                 data-provide="slider"
                 data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4]"
                 data-slider-ticks-labels='["Chart 1", "Chart 2", "chart 3", "chart 4" ]'
                 data-slider-ticks-values='["chart1", "chart2" , "chart3", "chart4"]'
                 data-slider-min="1"
                 data-slider-max="4"
                 data-slider-step="1"
                 data-slider-value="1"
                 data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

And I am using angularJS to fetch value of selected slider-tick.
Here is my code:

```js
angular.element($(this)).attr("data-value");
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: `angular.element($(this)).data("slider-value");` ??

Comment: Its not working . Showing same result "Undefined"....

Answer (score 0):

Using AngularJS, the simplest way is to use ng-model (ng-change is only for show purposes):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("inputExample", [])
  .controller("InputCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputChange = function() {
      alert($scope.yourInput);
  }
}])
</script>
<body ng-app="inputExample" ng-controller="InputCtrl">
  <input id="ex19" 
    ng-model="yourInput" 
    ng-change="inputChange()"
    type="text"
    data-provide="slider"
    data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4]"
    data-slider-ticks-labels='["Chart 1", "Chart 2", "chart 3", "chart 4" ]'
    data-slider-ticks-values='["chart1", "chart2" , "chart3", "chart4"]'
    data-slider-min="1"
    data-slider-max="4"
    data-slider-step="1"
    data-slider-value="1"
    data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
    
  {{yourInput}}

</body>
```